# Access to Documents file and metada on Content Server using DQL

Tags: documentum, documentum-dql

I would like to know whether there is a way to execute DQL queries against a content Documentum server apart from the JAVA API DFC classes interface, using other languages such as Python or R.

I need to access and old version of the documentum content Server, either 5.2 or 6.3 version. I have seen a REST API for the 7.1 and 7.2 versions of the content server

Thank you very much.

Comment: I am pretty sure that for such old version you won't be able to use REST API. I'm not sure when but you had DFS (Documentum Foundation Services) where you could write service to consume with Java or .NET clients via WSDL client implementation. But I'm not sure where it available before 6.5 SP2 version. Do you research :)

Answer (score 0):

About Documentum 5.2, it's impossible by DFS, even DFC if i'm not mistaken.
But 6.3 DFS could works.

I suggest you use the `idql(32).exe  or iapi(32).exe` (*.sh if linux) CMD program inside the Content Server Machine (`<DOCUMENTUM_HOME>\product\<6.3|5.3>\bin\*.*`).

You can even copy it to another machine, but probably you will need some extra DLLs also.

So, encapsulate this program using python, passing all necessary parameters.
Ex.: [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

check their sintaxs below:

```
 idql <docbase> [-U<user>] [-D<domain>] [-P<password>] [-K<secure flag>] [-R<input file>] [-n] [-l<error level>] [-X] [-z] [-w<display width>]

 iapi <docbase> [-U<username>] [-P<password>] [-D<domain>] [-K<secure flag>] [-R<input file>] [-i|-I] [-v] [-l<log file>] [-Q] [-F<failure level>] [-X] [-z] [-Sapi] [-w<column width>]
```

I dont remember if Documentum 5.3 is "dmbasic.exe" program instead "*idql*", but i'm pretty sure that "*iapi*" is there.

If works, you can not only execute querys, but even download a file from repository using iapi... totally old-school, but is possible. Search for "**Content Server API Reference
Manual Version 5.3**  guide to see what is possible to do.
I have a copy with me for emergencies. If you want i can send you by email.

Good luck.